# reading parts of a multi-level array from JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ok, I'm hoping this is not the same as other questions and I have looked for similar but can't find the answer... so here goes.
I get a JSON file and need to read the contents into a database. No sweat.
However I am having issue with reading the lowest levels as there can be a duplicate array.
I have all the data down to "comp".

Sample JSON file:

```
{
"code"   : 0,
"format" : 2,
"s_data" :
{
    "name" : "Lance",
    "club" : "Southern"
},
"d_data" :
{
    "errorcode" : 3,
    "errormsg" : ""
},
"timing" :
{
    "elapsed_time" : "08:29",
    "elapsed_time_secs" : 509,
    "comp" :
    [
        {
            "no" :
            [
            {
                    "sno"    : 0,
                    "xpos"   : 230.9,
                    "ypos"   : 97.2
                },
                {
                    "sno"    : 1,
                    "xpos"   : 132.4,
                    "ypos"   : 258.3
                },
                {
                    "sno"    : 2,
                    "xpos"   : 135.5,
                    "ypos"   : 176.7
                },  
            ]
        },
        {
            "no" :
            [
            {
                    "sno"    : 0,
                    "xpos"   : 250.9,
                    "ypos"   : 92.2
                },
                {
                    "sno"    : 1,
                    "xpos"   : 182.4,
                    "ypos"   : 158.3
                },
                {
                    "sno"    : 2,
                    "xpos"   : 145.5,
                    "ypos"   : 192.7
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So I want to now read the "no" data, but just the first instance of "no"... that is: sno, xpos, ypos foreach "sno" entry..

I'm thinking:

```
$mydata = json_decode(sample.json, true);
foreach($mydata->comp[0]->no as $values)
{
  echo $values->sno . "\n";
}
```

I get nothing back.
Any kind assistance appreciated.

Comment: Is `foreach($mydata->comp[0]->no as $values` even valid?!

Comment: With second parameter `true` `$mydata` will be an array. `Var_dump()` before you try to do anything.

Comment: @u_mulder - thanks, good idea to see what php sees inside the array.

Comment: @Naruto - not sure... got that from a googled piece of code and thought I'd try it. I'm ok with basic php but no wizard when it comes to -> stuff :)

Comment: the foreach statement is missing a closing bracket. Is it like this in your actual code? Because this would be invalid php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decode it in an associative array, you have to use it according, try this code:

```
foreach($mydata['timing']['comp'][0]['no'] as $values)
{
                echo $values['sno'] . "\n";
}
```

where all accesses to `$mydata` are using array style notation.

You have also to consider that the one posted is not a valid JSON string.

EDIT 20160122:
JSON string is now valid.

Comment: Following u_mulder's answer above I did a var_dump and can see the array structure. And Igor answered the question perfectly with the code.